# Align 3 divs with expanding at the middle

Tags: html, css

I want to make 3 divs(left, middle, right) in one line, the left and right divs with fixed width, while the middle one with expanding width(with percent use).
So far I tried couple of variants, but nothing do the job.
I want it something like that:

[...150px...][...100%...][...150px...]

While at the middle I'll be able to put a text that will brake line normally(without inline).

Sorry for my bad english.

I need it as much as possible adaptable for cross-browsering.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/ you want a fixed-fluid-fixed layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
.div1{
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
.div2{
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}
.middiv{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

But I would recommend you to use width for middiv by calculating yourself. For eg:

If the parent div width is `1000px` then your middiv would be `1000 - 300 = 700px`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just needed to float left the middiv, otherwise I can' make it work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fixedCell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="fixedCell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    display:table;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}

.fixedCell {
    width:150px;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:red;
}

.cell{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxt3gu11/

Comment: Lol... are you sure about that :-P ?

Comment: yes, for short you can check for can i use display table

Comment: it's much better than  "width: calc(100% - 300px);" . compare this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table with this http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: OK, if you check http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table , everything is green. Why is bad practice? Explain yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I would position the left and right parts absolutely and give the center a horizontal margin of 150px.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">centered text</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 150px;
}
```

Or see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/Fygow . If the left and right parts might have more content, add a clearfix to the row.